# Resize loginScreen (Background) or adjust Resolution of LightDM, CentOS 7

Tags: centos, login, size, lightdm, wallpaper

I'm using LightDM, but When I'm starting CentOS 7, the LightDM only take part of Screen, like low resolution.

Unfortunately I can't take a Screnshoot.

**How to adjust LightDM take all Size Screen?**

[image]

Comment: Did you install the VirtualBox Additions in the guest OS?

Comment: Yes, without LightDM work perfectly.